# An adjective describing a person that travels a lot

Tags: word-request

I used to know this adjective in English, but now I forgot. It describes a person who likes to travel a lot. It's a one-word adjective that, as far as I remember, sounds somewhat similar to the adjective "**hypothetical**". That adjective would probably fit into this simple sentence:

She is quite __________________ , so she travels a lot.

What is that adjective?

Comment: Is it peripatetic?

Comment: @RamPillai - YES!!!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: **Itinerant** is another candidate.

Comment: Only one L in 'travel'.

Comment: Usually, someone is peripatetic because they have to be (because of their job), and not because they like to be.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a few options here depending on the context of travel:

- peripatetic - which is mostly about job and business travel
- wayfaring - mostly to refer to travelling on foot
- errant - more of an adventurous traveller
- itinerant - someone who goes from place to place

Surely the first option fits as an answer to your question.